# Projection and transform lat,long coordinates in geo in OpenLayers

Tags: coordinate-system, openlayers, latitude-longitude, json

I am working on a project that from the ads-b data puts on the OpenLayers map the position of the intercepted planes ....

I encounter 2 problems:

1. The coordinates are in latitude and longitude and receive the following error:

> Collection.js: 292 Uncaught e {code: 58, name: "AssertionError",
> message: "Assertion failed. See
> https://openlayers.org/en/v5.3.0/doc/errors/#58 for details."}

Two plane icons are displayed but there are many more ...

2. I think it is a problem with the projection of coordinates because the coordinates should somehow fall in Romania or at least near Romania and they fall in southern Africa ....

[image]

The code that takes json from ads-b:

```
$.post( "data.php", 
                 {
                      get_data: 1
                 },
                 function( data ) { 
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    var aircrafts = obj.acList;
                    //console.log(aircrafts);
                    for(var i = 0; i<aircrafts.length; i++ ){
                        if(aircrafts[i].Long || aircrafts[i].Lat){
                            var coordinates = [aircrafts[i].Long, aircrafts[i].Lat];
                            console.log(coordinates);
                            addMarker(coordinates);
                        }
                    }
                    })
```

The code with which I try to display on the map the icons at the position in latitude and longitude:

```
function addMarker(coordinates) {
            
            proj4.defs('EPSG:31700','+proj=sterea +lat_0=46 +lon_0=25 +k=0.99975 +x_0=500000 +y_0=500000 +ellps=krass +towgs84=28,-121,-77,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs');                      
            ol.proj.proj4.register(proj4);
            
            console.log(coordinates);
            var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates).transform('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:31700'));
            console.log(marker);
            var zIndex = 1;
            
            marker.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({
              image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                anchor: [0.5, 36], 
                anchorXUnits: "fraction",
                anchorYUnits: "pixels",
                opacity: 1,
                src: "img/airport.png", 
                zIndex: zIndex
              })),
              zIndex: zIndex
            }));
            
            vectorSource.aircraft.addFeature(marker);
            map.addLayer(aircraft);  
          }
```

Exemple coordinate:

```
[29.746857, 42.511047]
```

!!!!!UPDATE!!!!

I was able to display all the intercepted planes in ads-b:

The line had to be moved: map.addLayer(aircraft); when taking over json

```
$.post( "data.php", 
                 {
                      get_data: 1
                 },
                 function( data ) { 
                    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
                    var aircrafts = obj.acList;
                    //console.log(aircrafts);
                    for(var i = 0; i<aircrafts.length; i++ ){
                        if(aircrafts[i].Long || aircrafts[i].Lat){
                            var coordinates = [aircrafts[i].Long, aircrafts[i].Lat];
                            console.log(coordinates);
                            addMarker(coordinates);
                        }
                    }
                    map.addLayer(aircraft);
                    })
```

[image]

Comment: Your map is in EPSG:3875 (Web Mercator) and your points are initially in EPSG:4326 and subsequently in  EPSG:31700 which is why they are spread out around Null Island

Comment: how could I solve this an example code please very nice if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feature coordinates must always be transformed to the view projection

```
var marker = new ol.Feature(new ol.geom.Point(coordinates).transform('EPSG:4326', map.getView().getProjection()));
```